# NP-hardness of maximizing convex quadratic over linear inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I have the following problem:
\begin{align}
\max_{x} \quad & \| x - \hat{x} \|_2^2 \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & x^\top a_i \leq b_i, \quad \forall i \in \{ 1,\ldots,N \},
\end{align}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the decision variable and $\hat{x}, a_1, \ldots, a_N, b_1, \ldots, b_N$ are given.

I would like to prove this problem is NP-hard. I have read that maximizing a quadratic form over a polytope is NP-hard, but I have not found a formal proof of this statement. Apparently, one can prove it using some kind of reduction argument to an 0-1 integer program, or to the $k$-clique problem, but I was not able to apply these arguments to my problem.

So my question is: how do I prove that my problem is NP-hard?

Comment: The objective is quadratic, but it is not a quadratic form

Comment: [Related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115547/53274)

Comment: [Related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17946/53274)

Comment: [Quadratic programming with one negative eigenvalue is NP-hard](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00120662) (1991)